# How to find closest similar value above current value, and return a different column on the same row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm looking for a way to find the closest similar value(in distance) **above** the current value(column B), and return the column next to that found value(column C) in column D.

A sort of vlookup where it finds the value closest to the search key in distance above.

Using cell D11 as a target/output example, I'd describe what I want something like this in pseudo code:

`Find value B11 in B1:B10, where distance from B11 is the smallest`, in this case B7, and then `return value in column C`, in this case the value in C7, and output results(52,921.07) it to D11.

Have a look at the blue arrows for a visualisation. I'm want to use the same principle for the other values as well.

[image: Finding the closest value above a current value]

Any ideas how to achieve this using Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete everything from Col D (including the header) and place the following in cell D1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Value X"; IF(B2:B="",, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B&COUNTIFS(B2:B, B2:B, ROW(B2:B),"<="&ROW(B2:B))-1, {B2:B&COUNTIFS(B2:B, B2:B, ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B)), C2:C}, 2, FALSE)))})`

A virtual array is formed between the curly brackets { }, with the header first and all results underneath (as signified by the colon). You can change the header as you like.

`IF(B2:B="",,`

If a cell in B2:B is blank, the corresponding cell in Col D will also be blank.

`COUNTIFS(B2:B, B2:B, ROW(B2:B),"<="&ROW(B2:B))`

Alone, this piece (which appears twice in the formula) keeps a count of each string in Col B for all rows less than or equal to the current row at any given point.

`VLOOKUP` will attempt to lookup a concatenation of the Col-B value and the `COUNTIFS` *value-minus-one* within a virtual array that contains a concatenation of the Col-B value and the *unaltered* `COUNTIFS` value in one column and the corresponding Col-C value in the second column, returning the second-column value if found.

`IFERROR` returns null if nothing is found (as will be the case for the first instance of each Col-B value).